# How to use zipcodes in Google GeoCharts

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

I'm trying to populate a geochart from [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart).

Basically I'm doing a count of people in `STATE, ZIPCODE, COUNT`. If i do only `STATE` and `COUNT`, it works fine. but when I try to add the zipcode, the map isn't being generated properly.

That's my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {
        'packages':['geochart'],
        // Note: you will need to get a mapsApiKey for your project.
        // See: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#load-settings
        'mapsApiKey': 'AIzaSyD-9tSrke72PouQMnMX-a7eZSW0jkFMBWY'
      });
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

      function drawRegionsMap() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['State', 'Count'],
            ['FL', 16],
            ['MA', 2149],
            ['NY', 2784],
            ['NC', 9782],
            ['PA', 9923],
            ['WA', 15],

            <!-- i want to be able to have the following on the geochart -->
            /*['State', 'Zip Code', 'Count'],
            ['AZ',85013,1],
            ['CA',91945,12],
            ['CA',96003,1],
            ['CA',18045,25],
            ['CA',92377,1],
            ['CA',93703,10],
            ['CA',95407,1],
            ['CA',93720,6],
            ['CA',93619,1],
            ['CA',92009,8],
            ['CA',93727,1],
            ['CO',80003,5],
            ['CO',80004,1],
            ['CO',80220,2],
            ['CO',80504,8],
            ['CO',80134,21],
            ['CO',80016,1],
            ['CO',80228,19],
            ['CO',80111,3],
            ['CT',06795,1],
            ['CT',06762,12],*/

        ]);

        var options = {
        region: 'US',
            displayMode: 'markers',
            resolution: 'provinces',
            colorAxis: {colors: ['#fff9ef', '#fffa00']}
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="regions_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I don't understand why when I add the zip code to the data, it just return a blank map. If I change the `resolution` to `'metros'`, it seems to give a more granular level in the map as compared to `'provinces'`.

Is this something that's possible in google GeoCharts?

Comment: see the data format for [markers mode](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart#markers-mode-format) -- _The first column is a specific string address (for example, "1600 Pennsylvania Ave")._ -- you could possibly use the zip code for the first column, but there can only be one column -- __or__ -- _The first two columns are numeric, where the first column is the latitude, and the second column is the longitude._ -- this actually loads markers the fastest, almost instantly.

Comment: I don't have easy access to the long and lat. Is there a way of doing it just by zip codes and count?

Comment: maybe try zip as the first column, but as `'string'` instead of `number` -- fyi: you can get lat / lng here --> [https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=address&sensor=false&key=apikey](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=address&sensor=false&key=apikey)